# How to use variables in bash grep?

Tags: bash, grep

```
#!/bin/bash

host=${1-localhost}
port=${2-27017}
dbname=${3-ascq}

MONGOBKDIR=./mongo_data/ascq
echo "restore data from $MONGOBKDIR"

dbs=$(mongo $host:$port --eval 'printjson(db.adminCommand("listDatabases"))' | \
            grep -oP '"name" : "${dbname}\d*"' | \
            awk '{print $3}' | tr -d '"')

for i in $dbs
do
    echo "restoring:$i"
    mongorestore -h $host:$port -d $i --drop $MONGOBKDIR/
done

exit 0
```

I want to use ${dbname} in grep but failed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818079/how-to-grep-a-variable-in-the-shell-program

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add grep command to bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142729/add-grep-command-to-bash-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using single quotes which would prevent expansion of the variable.

Use double quotes:

```
grep -oP "name : ${dbname}\d*"
```

If you also want to match quotes `"` in the pattern, escape those:

```
grep -oP "\"name\" : \"${dbname}\d*\""
```

Comment: Thank you. But @Mario's is early.

Comment: @goofansu It's ok.  However, I'm not sure how define *early*.  When the time *elapsed* is provided, then the larger value is *early*.

Comment: We were probably writing at the same time.  I like your answer better, and this is what counts the most (to me, and in the long run: you will see :-) ).  +1

Answer (score 3):

Try `grep -oP '"name" : "'${dbname}'\d*"'` .

Inside apostrophes (single quotes), variable expansion does not occur.

I assume input contains quotes (double ones) that you want to match, as in

```
"name" : "sales34567"
"name" : "payroll34567"
```